# qr function in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use qr function in perl and also want to do Case insensitive regex matching. Below is what I am trying to do:

```
my $pattern = qr(Buy Qty\[([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\]);
my $logPattern = "BUY Qty[200000]  On merchant site";

if($logPattern =~ /$pattern/i){
    print "MatchFound, Qty is ==> $1";
else {
    print "Match Not found";
}
```

However When I run this, it gives me "Match Not found" as it is not making this regex match as case insensitive. However if I remove the qr code and use the same pattern , it gives me the correct answer.

Please do let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile regex with `/i` switch

```
my $pattern = qr(Buy Qty\[([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)\])i;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...but why it ignored that /i switch in the m// context

Comment: @ANewDeveloper [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) suggests `/msixpodual` flags to be used when compiling regex.

Comment: @ANewDeveloper, It didn't get ignored. `$re=qr/a/; 'Aa'=~/a$re/i` will match. It simply won't apply to the subpattern that you specified should use case-sensitive matching.